# ember.js RestAdapter How to define ajaxoptions

Tags: mongodb, ember.js, restheart

I customized **RESTAdapter** to connect to a RestHeart server (a RestFull web 
 gateway server for mongodb):

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  host:'http://127.0.0.1:8080',
  namespace: 'boards'
});
```

I created a model to test :

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  identity: DS.attr()
});
```

Everything works fine, but when I use the save method on a record (developer):
I have a warning in the browser console :

> The server returned an empty string for POST
>   http://.../boards/Developer, which cannot be parsed into a valid JSON.
>   Return either null or {}.

and the folowing error :

> SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
>       at parse ()
>       at ajaxConvert (jquery.js:8787)
>       at done (jquery.js:9255)
>       at XMLHttpRequest. (jquery.js:9548)

I know why :
The RESTAdapter is waiting for a JSON response, and the restHeart server returns an empty response when adding => so jQuery causes an error when it tries to parse the null response.

With previous versions of ember-data, it was possible to set the dataType variable of jQuery ajax requests to '*' using the hook **ajaxOptions** this way:

```
export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  ajaxOptions(url, type, options) {
    var hash = this._super(url, type, options);
    hash.dataType = "*";
    return hash;
  },
  host:'http://127.0.0.1:8080',
  namespace: 'boards'
});
```

With ember-data 2.16, **ajaxOptions** is now private, and I do not know how to modify the dataType variable... so that the null response is not parsed as a JSON response

Versions :

- ember-data 2.16
- ember 2.18

Comment: Instead of making an edit to your question, you should put your solution as an answer to your question.

Answer (score 2):

### Solution found

```
export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  ajaxOptions: function(url, type, options) {
    // get the default RESTAdapter 'ajaxOptions'
    var hash = this._super(url, type, options);

    // override if it's a POST request
    if (type == 'POST') {
      hash.dataType = 'text';
    }
    return hash;
  },

  ajaxSuccess: function(jqXHR, data) {
    if (typeof data === 'string') {
      // return an empty object so the Serializer handles it correctly
      return {};
    } else {
      return data;
    }
  },
  host:'http://127.0.0.1:8080',
  namespace: 'boards'
});
```

It works without any warning or error,strangely, 
because I don't know if I respect the encapsulation of the RESTAdapter class ...

see [Ember-data 2.6 & 2.7 release notes](https://www.emberjs.com/blog/2016/06/09/ember-data-2-6-released.html#toc_code-ds-improved-ajax-code-a-href-https-github-com-emberjs-data-pull-3099-3099-a)